# UpdatePanel refreshes only once

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, refresh

I have two updatepanels inside an accordion control, laid out like this:

```
<accordion>
   <first pane content>
      <updatepanel UpdateMode="conditional">
         <contenttemplate>...</contenttemplate>
         <triggers>...</triggers>
      </updatepanel>
   </first pane content>

   <second pane content>
       <updatepanel>
          <contenttemplate>...</contenttemplate>
          <triggers>...</triggers>
       </updatepanel>
  </second pane content>

</accordion>
```

The panel updates once, but after that, no updates take place. If I refresh the page, then I can see the updated information. This means that the database is being updated, but the updatepanel isn't refreshing (after refreshing the first time). Why is this happening?

This has been bugging me for days, so any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

**update**

The problem seems to lie when I call this:

```
Sys.require(Sys.components.accordion, function() {
                    $("#acca_profile").accordion({
                        HeaderCssClass: "acc_header",
                        HeaderSelectedCssClass: "acc_selectedheader",
                        FadeTransitions: true,
                        suppressHeaderPostbacks: true,
                        requireOpenedPane: false
                    });



                });
```

in the `endRequestHandler` function. However, if I don't call it, then the div that should  be converted to an accordion is no longer an accordion.

**Update 2**

After a bit more work, I figured the problem may lie in the fact that the Jquery is not rebinding the events after the partial postback. A lot of solutions claim that you have to register the client script, but I have this at the top of my aspx page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
<Scripts>
```

... (other script)
 Path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" />

```
</Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

How can I rebind the JQuery events in my code?

Comment: I would need to see more code to help

Comment: Have you checked if you are getting any javascript errors? You can use firebug or whatever you like to do that.

Comment: Ah, I found the error seems to be in a function that's called in the endRequestHandler section. At the moment, when the updatepanel refreshes, the accordion disappears (i.e. the javascript used to convert a div to an accordion is no longer executed). I tried to execute it in the endRequestHandler, and although that works, the refreshing stops. I've updated my post with the accordion code.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I think I've solved it! Hours down the drain for a few lines of code. Isn't that always the way? :D
For people who come across this thread, I added:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(pLoad);
```

I then created a function called `pLoad` which contained the my accordion javascript (in original post), as well as a couple of other functions.
So far things seem to be working...